# Can't get backbone routing to work for regex

Tags: regex, backbone.js, coffeescript

I tried adding the `@route` to `initialize` to be able to use regex when routing. But the login view doesn't fire in this instance and I'm unable to understand what goes awry.

class AppRouter extends Backbone.Router

```
    # routes:
    #   '':                     'login'
    #   'login':                'login'
    #   '?*param':              'login'
    #   'logout':               'logout'
    #   'forgotten':            'forgotten'
    #   'login/forgotten':      'forgotten'
    #   'forgotten-password':   'forgotten'
    #   'reset/:token':         'reset'

    initialize: ->
        @route(/^login/, 'login')
        @forgottenView  = new ForgottenView(@)

    login: (param) ->
        loginView = new LoginView(@, param)
        loginView.render()
    logout: -> @loginView.logout()

    forgotten: ->
        if Config.App.accountName.length > 0
            @forgottenView.render(noAccount=false, Config.App.accountName)
        else
            @forgottenView.render(noAccount=true)

    reset: (token) ->
        resetView = new ResetView(@, token)
        resetView.render()


exports =
    initialize: ->
        appRouter = new AppRouter()

        exports.getInitialRoute = appRouter.getInitialRoute

        Backbone.history.start({pushState: true, root: Config.App.baseUrl})

return exports
```

Comment: " Each matching capture from the route or regular expression will be passed as an argument to the callback. " - Perhaps, you seek `@route(/^(login)/, 'login')`? Have a look at http://backbonejs.org/#Router.

Comment: Nope, it's just that the router doesn't trigger at all. So this isn't the issue.